# como resolver una ecuación

Tags: javascript

Y luego tengo otra duda de otro ejercicio, que me pide calcular el producto de todos los números del array con forEach

Sobre la pregunta del foreach lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
let datos = []; 
(var x = 1; x <= 50; x ++) {
    datos.push (x); 
}
```

Y lo que me pide es lo siguiente: Calcula el producto de todos los números del array "datos" con forEach.

Comment: Por favor, cambiale el titulo a la pregunta, y ponele "como resolver una ecuación", para que otros usuarios lo puedan entender. Tambien tratá de poner solo una cosa en una pregunta, así la gente que tiene la misma consulta, puede entender solo una. Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Aparentemente, en el código que subiste olvidaste colocar el `for`.

Comment: Gbianchi, soy nueva aquí y me cuesta saber como hacer una pregunta adecuadamente para que sea aceptada

Comment: y no leiste ninguno de los links que te deje en mi comentario no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso del forEach, podrías agregar:

```
let resultado = 1;
datos.forEach((e) => {
  resultado = resultado * e;
});
```